# Need help in setup of CI/CD for Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, devops

We are building an addon using Google App Script and want to publish it to Google Workspace MarketPlace. We are managed to publish versioned deployment using the [Manage Deployment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments.) feature of App Script.

We are looking to configure CI/CD for App Script addon (whenever changes committed to a git branch, a new deployment id should be created and respective code should be published on Google Workspace MarketPlace).

We didn't find any workaround to configure CI/CD for App Script. Our preference is Azure for CI/CD.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of the

#### [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api)

Where you can manage deployments and versions.

#### [Workspace Marketplace API](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/reference/rest)

Where you can control your app listing.

You may not be able to do absolutely everything but that will be your best place to start.

I am not familiar with Azure but you can look into git actions to run some API request to the above APIs whenever you make a commit to the main branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use App script API for publishing the code to Apps script project using your respective client libraires, in my case I have used golang and library https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/script/v1.

Example for pushing the code. Refer their documentation https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/go

For Creating a new deployment using go library refer the documentation: https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/script/v1#ProjectsDeploymentsService.Create

For Deploying your latest code : You needed to create a new version first and then perform the deployment.

1. Create a new version using version create call (https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/script/v1#ProjectsVersionsService.Create)
2. Deploy the new version using deployment update call (https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/script/v1#ProjectsDeploymentsService.Update)